# First click of Unity UI Button does not respond

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm trying to use Unity's UI system .

What I want is that I have a button #1 as a card image and I have button 2 as a spade image. First I will click spade image and it's indicator will turn on. After that I will click the card image to make the Spade Icon image disappear. I managed to get variables from script to another script but whatever I do the first click of the Spade Button, the indicator lights up and `spadeselected` bool changes in the inspector. While `spadeselected` is true, the first click of the Card image doesn't do a thing. After clicking twice and so on everything works fine. What could cause this problem?

My `main` script for card button:

```
public class main : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool ace = false;
    
    spadestatement _spadestatement;
    public GameObject spadebutton;
        
    public GameObject spade_icon;

    private void Awake()
    { 
        _spadestatement = spadebutton.GetComponent<spadestatement>();
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        gameObject.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(turnoff);
    }

    private void turnoff()
    {
        ace ^= true;
        
        if (_spadestatement.spadeselected == true)
        {   
            spade_icon.SetActive(ace);
        }
    }
}
```

My `spadestatement` script for spade button:

```
public class spadestatement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool spadeselected;
    public GameObject indicator;

    void Start()
    {
        gameObject.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(select);
    }

    public void select()
    {
        spadeselected ^= true;
        indicator.SetActive(spadeselected);
    }
}
```

And here is a picture to make it more understandable:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `spadeselected` is true, the first time you call `turnoff()` :

```
private void turnoff()
{
    ace ^= true; //first time : after the assignment, ace is true
    
    if (_spadestatement.spadeselected == true)
    {   
        spade_icon.SetActive(ace); // since ace is true, set spade_icon active
    }
}
```

The second time you call `turnoff()`, `ace` become `false`, thus spade_icon is deactive.

If you want to turn on/off the spade_icon, maybe try this one:

```
private void turnoff()
{
    ace ^= true; //first time : after the assignment, ace is true
    
    if (_spadestatement.spadeselected == true)
    {   
        spade_icon.SetActive(!ace); // since ace is true, set spade_icon deactive
    }
}
```

Or, if you don't want to bind the active/deactive behaviour of `spade_icon` with `ace`, you can:

```
private void turnoff()
{
    if (_spadestatement.spadeselected == true)
    {   
        spade_icon.SetActive(!spade_icon.activeSelf);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wanted to suggest the same: get rid of those bool flags / or at least initialize them with the correct state of `spade_icon.activeSelf` / `indicator.activeSelf` ... better to not use the flags at all though .. only introduces more pitfalls of having to sync the value with the actual active state of the objects